# How do I ignore mouse events on child elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list with mouseover and mouseout events attached to the li elements. Each contains a link and there is a bit of padding in the li. When I mouseover the li the mouseover event is fired, but when I mouseover the link *contained* in the li the mouseout and the mouseover events are both fired in order. It seems the child elements are firing their parent elements mouse events...how do I go about stopping this? I want it to just stay mouseovered when mousing over the links, not activating the animations every time I mouse over a link. This is my code;

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#menu li ul').hide();
      jQuery('#menu li').mouseover( function() {
           jQuery(this).children("ul").show('fast').stop;
           return false;
      });
      jQuery('#menu li').mouseout( function() {
           jQuery(this).children("ul").hide('fast').stop;
           return false;
      });
 });

 <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="">Some link</a>
           <ul>Sub content</ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems I've found the answer to my own question. For anyone who might have the same problem; try this code instead. It seems hover doesn't bubble into child elements like the other mouse events do.

```
jQuery('#menu li').hover(
    function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').show('fast');
        return false;
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
        return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 15):

Use "event.**[stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)**()" to stop the events from bubbling upwards:

```
  jQuery('#menu li a').mouseover( function(evt) {
       evt.stopPropagation();
       return false;
  });
  jQuery('#menu li a').mouseout( function(evt) {
       evt.stopPropagation();
       return false;
  });
```

Alternatively use the **[mouseenter](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter#fn)** and **[mouseleave](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseleave#fn)** events instead of mouseover/out. jQuery normalizes their behaviour across browsers and these events have the benefit of not bubbling...

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I also tried using mouseenter and mouseleave and they don't do anything either.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't *quite* right. It removes the mouseover from the link, but the mouseout is being called from the li element, not the link--so it's just flashing open and then closed again when I try to mouse over it.

Comment: The above solution suggested by Stephen himself looks more straightforward though, but good point if you need the handlers to act slightly different for instance.

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for the equivelant behavior in JS where in AS3 you can put:

```
object.mouseenabled = false;
```

The way I found that works pretty well is to use CSS and put:

```
.element { pointer-events: none; }
```

(but I guess that only works if you don't need the element for anything at all. I use it for tooltips that pop up on hover, but don't want it to act weird when you move your mouse away).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$('#menu li').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        //Show ul
    } else {
        //Hide ul
    }
});
```

The advantage is a usage of event delegation.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use css classes to distinguish the different menu levels. You can then easily search for one class or the other in your jQuery selectors.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be overly difficult as this is for use with wordpress, which injects all of this dynamically and it's rather complicated to filter the output.