# hide a div when clicking on the outer container using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs, one overlayed on top of another. When I click on the outer div, I want to hide the inner div. When I click on the inner div nothing should happen to the inner Div. At the same time, the links in the inner div should work fine. How to do it using jquery?

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

.outer {
    background-color: #000;  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 240px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

jQuery code that doesn't work as expected:

```
$('.outer').click(function(e){
    $('.inner').hide();
});

$('.inner').click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you're hiding the inner div all of it's children will be hidden too, and therefor not clickable.

Comment: Also see these posts - [Jquery click event propagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244320/jquery-click-event-propagation) / [Ignore mouse events on child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766286/how-do-i-ignore-mouse-events-on-child-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost always done by preventing bubbling. Since any click on `.inner` will bubble up to `.outer`, we need to prevent those clicks:

```
$(".outer")
    .on("click", function () {
        $(this).find(".inner").slideUp();
    })
    .on("click", ".inner", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22Uz7/
Fiddle (using your CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/22Uz7/1/

You indicated that you were using jQuery 1.4.2 in the comments below. As such, you won't have access to the `.on` method - the following code should work under 1.4.2:

```
$(".outer").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).find(".inner").slideUp();
});

$(".inner").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22Uz7/3/

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` - return false; in OP's code is already doing that. Both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation

Comment: Hm... But because of e.preventDefault() caused by return false; links will not work.

Comment: getting uncaught syntax error : Unexpected token illegal error while using the above code- is it because I'm using jquery 1.4.2. I tried bind, delegate too instead of 'on'

Comment: @web_dev Why are you using jQuery 1.4.2? That version is [nearly 3 years old](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/)...

Comment: Thanks for the effort in giving a solution. Unfortunately jQuery 1.4.2 is what my client is using in many of its sites and not willing to upgrade it as of now. Finally got it working by the solution suggested at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Comment: @web_dev I'm sorry to hear that you're stuck with 1.4.2. I'll update my answer with a version that will work with that version as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `event.target` to specify your action only if the target class name matches `outer`:

```
$('.outer').click(function(ev){
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target.className.match(/\bouter\b/)) {
        $(this).find('.inner').toggle();
    }
});​​​​​​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QzeY3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

do something like this?

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
   $('.inner').css('display', 'none');
});
```

or for it's child

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.inner').css('display', 'none');
});
```