# How to prevent onmouseover from firing inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rectangular div, with a few smaller divs and images inside of the rectangle.  I want to be able to animate the whole div upward a little bit on mouse enter, to show more information.  Then, when mouse exits the div, I want the div to return to previous position.  However, the function fires when I enter a child div or image, and again when I exit that child div.  I basically want onmouseover to ignore the children divs.  Is this possible with Javascript/Jquery?  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766286/how-do-i-ignore-mouse-events-on-child-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Filter element using event target property:

```
$(parent).on('mouseover',function(e){
    if(e.target !== this) return;
    //...
});
```

But depending what you are looking for, using `mouseenter` could be a solution too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.parentClass:not(.childrenClass)').mouseover(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way of doing this is:

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

the basic javascript way of doing this is:

event.preventDefault();

Comment: `.preventDefault()`? Are you sure about this?

Comment: This prevents bubbling of the event chain calls that will eventually trigger your script.

Comment: You started the answer right, mentioning `.stopPropagation`, but finished it wrongly.